# New Physics contributions to the Wilson Coefficients

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, beyond-the-standard-model, effective-field-theory

[image: Leading New Physics contributions to the Wilson Coefficients]

In this article ([arXiv:1507.06660v1 [hep-ph]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.06660)), the authors tried to extend the SM by adding a new sector, consisting of vector-like quarks and leptons $Q$, $L$ and two scalars $\phi$, $\chi$. They also added a new $U(1)_X$ group to the SM gauge group, and $Z'$ is the corresponding new gauge boson.

The above diagram has a new contribution to the Wilson coefficients $C^{\mu}_{9,10}$, corresponding to the operators $\overline{b}\gamma_{\rho}(1-\gamma^5)s\;\overline{\mu}\gamma^{\rho}\mu$ and $\overline{b}\gamma_{\rho}(1-\gamma^5)s\;\overline{\mu}\gamma^{\rho}\gamma^5\mu$.

I can understand up to this point, but my question is why there's only that one diagram that contributes? I mean, since $Q$ has an EM charge, it will interact with the photon $\gamma$. Also, $\gamma$ can interact directly with the muons. So in the above diagram, if we replace $Z'$ by $\gamma$, we will have a new diagram that also makes a new physics contribution to the Wilson coefficients, right? Why did they ignore that?
Could somebody help me understand that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wilson coefficients $C_9$ and $C_{10}$ from the weak effective Hamiltonian at the scale $\sim m_b$ are calculated by integrating out heavy degrees of freedom from the theory.   In this case the vector-like fermions, the top quark, W, Z, and the scalars.    The electromagnetic gauge symmetry is still present on the weak effective Hamiltonian, so one does not generate photon mediated contributions to $C_9$ and $C_{10}$ at the scale $\sim m_b$.

To your question about the photon mediated contribution, you will need to do the calculation to convince yourself that such vertex $b-s-\gamma$ is not induced via the mixing of the fermions and the vector-like quarks.  The reason is that the vector like quark has the same quantum numbers under the SM than the SM quark field it mixes with.   This implies that when diagonalizing the electromagnetic current (due to fermion mixing with the vector-like quarks) you end up with flavour diagonal interactions of the photon in the fermion mass basis.

Comment: Sorry for the long response. I thought no one was going to answer me anymore. About your second point, I've re-checked and realized that the $b-s-\gamma$ vertex indeed doesn't appear in the mass basis like you said. Thank you for pointing that out for me.